# $this->request->getData() return inappropriate response in case of post json array in cakephp 3.5

Tags: php, json, rest, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using the cakephp 3.5 to create the REST APIs. I have create an controller and method inside controller when i post the data to controller using POST MEN tools. it returning me an unexpected response

**Below is the json array that i am trying use in post data**

```
{
    "type": true,
    "userRole": "customer",
    "signupType": "test",
    "userProfile": {
        "email": "admin@test.com",
        "password": "YLhdh3UfH/oqppQ/P4wUBw==",
        "first_name": "admin",
        "last_name": "admin",
        "phone_no": "admin",
        "profile_image": "test.jpg",
        "street_address": "test address",
        "state": "Chandigarh",
        "city": "Chandigarh",
        "zipcode": "160022",
        "latitude": "30.723306",
        "longitude": "76.766114",
        "rating": "5",
        "role": "customer",
        "status": "1"
    }
}
```

**And Here is the data that i m getting inside method :-**

```
Array
(
    [{"type":"true","userRole":"customer","signupType":"gojus","userProfile":{"email":"admin@gojus_com","password":"YLhdh3UfH/oqppQ/P4wUBw] => =","first_name":"admin","last_name":"admin","phone_no":"admin","profile_image":"test.jpg","street_address":"test address","state":"Chandigarh","city":"Chandigarh","zipcode":"160022","latitude":"30.723306","longitude":"76.766114","rating":"5","role":"customer","status":"1"}}
)
```

This is the issues inside get data that i am getting **"[{"**  how can i resolve the issues in cakephp 3.5

Comment: Can You show Your code. You're using `Client` class?

Answer (score 1):

Read the Manual: [XML or JSON Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#xml-or-json-data)

> Applications employing REST often exchange data in non-URL-encoded
>   post bodies. You can read input data in any format using
>   Http\ServerRequest::input(). By providing a decoding function, you can
>   receive the content in a deserialized format:

```
// Get JSON encoded data submitted to a PUT/POST action
$jsonData = $this->request->input('json_decode');
```